# convert string results to array in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a code:

```
$x = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'testrg1' -Name 'sqlvm1'-CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Users\joe\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\joe\Miscellaneous\run_sqlserver_script.ps1' -Parameter @{"VmName" = 'sqlvm1'}
```

Output of $x:
[image]

Type of X:
[image]

I want the stuff in the Message to be in an array so that I can access each value. But right now $x.Value[0].Message.gettype() is a String. When I run $x.Value[0].Message.ComputerName nothing shows up. How do I convert the stuff in the Message from String to Array?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you will have to post the contents of the script `run_sqlserver_script.ps1`...its probably either converting or assigning string values to the message property.

Comment: Or [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) or [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) `$x` and add the results (as text) to the question.

Comment: @Kiran This is the content  ```#Calling Named Parameters
param([string]$VmName)

#Invoke SQL Script on the VMs
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $VmName -query "SELECT  
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS 'VirtualMachineName', 
  SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS 'ServerName',  
  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS 'Edition',
  SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS 'EngineEdition',
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS 'ProductVersion',  
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS 'ProductLevel'" ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you show `$x.Value[0].Message.gettype()` is a string looking like the output of `Format-List`

```
ComputerName     : sqlvm1
InstanceName     : sqlvm1
Edition          : Developer Edition (64-bit)
EngineEdition    : 3
ProductVersion   : 15.0.4138.2
ProductLevel     : RTM
```

you can parse that out like:

```
($x.Value[0].Message -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData).ComputerName
```

Regex details on the `-replace` to replace only the first occurrence of the colon:

```
(?<!        Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   :        Match the character “:” literally
   .        Match any single character
      *     Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)          
:           Match the character “:” literally
```