# Convert String to Array of Objects in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an array of strings that I need to convert to array of objects.

Here is an example:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $datasets[0]
id                               : 11111
name                             : test1
addRowsAPIEnabled                : False
configuredBy                     : xxxx
isRefreshable                    : True
isEffectiveIdentityRequired      : False
isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired : False
targetStorageMode                : Abf
createdDate                      : 2019-02-12T16:43:01.047Z
contentProviderType              : PbixInImportMode
upstreamDatasets                 : {}
users                            : {}
isInPlaceSharingEnabled          : False

id                               : 22222
name                             : test2
addRowsAPIEnabled                : False
configuredBy                     : xxxx
isRefreshable                    : True
isEffectiveIdentityRequired      : False
isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired : False
targetStorageMode                : Abf
createdDate                      : 2019-07-15T15:53:15.057Z
contentProviderType              : PbixInImportMode
upstreamDatasets                 : {}
users                            : {}
isInPlaceSharingEnabled          : False
```

The datatype is String

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $datasets[0].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

As the final result, I would like to break down the elements of the nested arrays(that is string datatype now) by object and concatenate these into one general array.

I tried the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585576/convert-string-results-to-array-in-powershell)

```
$datasets[0] -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

But I get an error about duplicate keys.

I also tried to convert from json `$datasets[0] | ConvertFrom-Json`, but it throws an error.

Do you know a good approach in this case?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75303629/how-to-import-an-array-of-psobjects-from-a-text-file/75304609

Comment: This is precisely what I need! Thank you!

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, Could you create an answer that I can accept?

Comment: I have closed this one since its a duplicate of the one linked. @ me again if any doubts